# Round dbl to nearlest integer and convert to ordered factor in R

Tags: r

I have a numeric column within a dataframe that I want to round to the nearest integer and then convert into an ordered factor.  This seems fairly straight forward, but I can't figure out why this isn't working as expected.

```
# example data
tmp <- structure(list(variable1 = c(X1 = 3.66666666666667, X2 = 2.66666666666667, 
                                    X3 = 3.33333333333333, X4 = 3, X5 = 2, X6 = 2, X7 = NA, X8 = 3.33333333333333, 
                                    X9 = 2.66666666666667, X10 = 4, X11 = 3.66666666666667, X12 = 3, 
                                    X13 = 3.66666666666667, X14 = 3.33333333333333, X15 = 3.33333333333333, 
                                    X16 = 4, X17 = 3.33333333333333, X18 = 3, X19 = 3, X20 = 3, X21 = 3, 
                                    X22 = 3.33333333333333, X23 = 3.33333333333333, X24 = 2.66666666666667, 
                                    X25 = 2, X26 = 3.33333333333333, X27 = 3, X28 = 3, X29 = 2.66666666666667)), 
                 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -29L))

# round to the nearest integer
scores <- round(tmp, digits = 0)

# convert to an ordered factor
factors <-
  ordered(
    scores,
    levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
    labels = c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree")
  )
```

This code returns the following:

```
variable1 
     <NA> 
Levels: Strongly Disagree < Disagree < Agree < Strongly Agree
```

I thought it was because of the `NA` in my dataset, but I still get the same thing after omitting NA.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are passing a data frame and not a vector to `ordered()`:

```
str(scores)
# Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 29 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ variable1: num  4 3 3 3 2 2 NA 3 3 4 ...
```

But `ordered()` needs a vector:

> ordered(x, ...)
>
> x: a vector of data, usually taking a small number of distinct
>             values.

Use `scores$variable1` instead:

```
factors <-
  ordered(
    scores$variable1,
    levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
    labels = c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly Agree")
  )


factors
# [1] Strongly Agree Agree          Agree          Agree          Disagree      
# [6] Disagree       <NA>           Agree          Agree          Strongly Agree
# [11] Strongly Agree Agree          Strongly Agree Agree          Agree         
# [16] Strongly Agree Agree          Agree          Agree          Agree         
# [21] Agree          Agree          Agree          Agree          Disagree      
# [26] Agree          Agree          Agree          Agree         
# Levels: Strongly Disagree < Disagree < Agree < Strongly Agree
```